# Текстовая информация в поле INTEGER SQLite

Tags: база-данных, sqlite

Есть БД SQLite. В ней есть таблица с полем INTEGER.

При попытке сохранить в это поле текстовые данные они сохраняются и отображаются нормально как текст, хотя по-хорошему должно быть исключение.

Что это может быть? Баг или фича SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из [документации](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> SQLite uses a more general dynamic type system. In SQLite, the
> datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its
> container.
>
> Any column in an SQLite version 3 database, except an INTEGER PRIMARY
> KEY column, may be used to store a value of any storage class.

Из [FAQ](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q3):

> **SQLite lets me insert a string into a database column of type integer!**
>
> This is a feature, not a bug. SQLite uses dynamic typing. It does not
> enforce data type constraints. Data of any type can (usually) be
> inserted into any column. You can put arbitrary length strings into
> integer columns, floating point numbers in boolean columns, or dates
> in character columns. The datatype you assign to a column in the
> CREATE TABLE command does not restrict what data can be put into that
> column. Every column is able to hold an arbitrary length string.
> (There is one exception: Columns of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY may only
> hold a 64-bit signed integer. An error will result if you try to put
> anything other than an integer into an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column.)
>
> But SQLite does use the declared type of a column as a hint that you
> prefer values in that format. So, for example, if a column is of type
> INTEGER and you try to insert a string into that column, SQLite will
> attempt to convert the string into an integer. If it can, it inserts
> the integer instead. If not, it inserts the string. This feature is
> called type affinity.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!